# Is it possible to make this 2D array print with no reoccuring values?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, random

Here is my current randomized 2D array, I need to make each array print to have no repeating values within the parameters. I have already tried other posts, but none of them cover multidimensional arrays and specifically Math.random.

Also is it even possible with the way I have arranged this table of array values? As later on I will need to be able to test them for user input.
Thank you for your time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("B  I  N  G  O");
    int[][] board = new int[5][5];

    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
       for(int j =0; j <board.length; j++){
           board[0][j] = (int)(Math.random() *15) +1;
           board[1][j] = (int)(Math.random() *15) +16;
           board[2][j] = (int)(Math.random() *15) +31;
           board[2][2] = 0;
           board[3][j] = (int)(Math.random() *15) +46;
           board[4][j] = (int)(Math.random() *15) +61;
           System.out.printf("%-3s", board[j][i]);
       }
       System.out.println("");
    }  
}
```

}

Comment: all dimensions. So at board[0][0]. which is the first number under column B, to board[0][4] which is the last number under column B. And so on for each letter printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ArrayList for keeping all the used Integers.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Solution  {
    static ArrayList<Integer> random=new ArrayList<Integer>();  
    private static Random r = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("B  I  N  G  O");
        int[][] board = new int[5][5];        
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
           for(int j =0; j <board.length; j++){
               if(j==0)
                   board[i][j] = getUniqueRandom(15, 1);
               else if(j==1)
                   board[i][j] = getUniqueRandom(30, 16);
               else if(j==2)
                   board[i][j] = getUniqueRandom(45, 31);
               else if(j==3)
                   board[i][j] = getUniqueRandom(60, 46);
               else if(j==4)
                   board[i][j] = getUniqueRandom(75, 61);
               if(i==board.length/2 && j==board.length/2) board[i][j] = 0;
               System.out.printf("%-3s", board[i][j]);
           }
           System.out.println("");     
    }
    }
    static int getUniqueRandom(int max, int min){
        int num = r.nextInt(max-min+1) + min;
        while (random.contains(num)) {
            num = r.nextInt(max-min+1) + min;
        }
        random.add(num);
        return num;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works like a Charm, I've been up all night stumped on this. could not find anywhere on Stack / Google how to convert my caveman code into something working and slimmed down. I've already corrected it, and now I'm working on a user input method that checks the input against the array for BINGO.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a list with list of possible numbers from 0, 1, 2, 3,..., #rows * #columns
2. Choose a random number, 'randomInteger' between 0 and max length of your current list.
3. Assign list[randomNumber] to current board[i][j] and remove that number from your list.
4. Likewise, do until all numbers in your list are removed.

You are likely to achieve your expected result.

Comment: So essentially scrap the nested for loop I created? because it will give me problems later on when im trying to test user inputs against the values if its a multidimensional array right?